# levelDB performance differences between python and java

Tags: leveldb

I've been trying with levelDB data load with python and java and got a somewhat big surprise when a simple test showed much better and consistent performance in python than in java.

With java tried:

- org.iq80.leveldb version version 0.9 (native java impl) => The
  preferred option
- org.fusesource.leveldbjni version 1.8 (jni bridge to
  C++ native impl)

With Python:

- happynear/py-leveldb-windows

Inserting (just that) a RDF dataset of 1M triples, i got these results (the values are unimportant, I guess, just the diffs):

- Java native: 26 secs average (big variations of timings for each 1k insert batch)
- Java JNI: blocked most of the runs
- Python: 6 seconds average (consistently, almost no variations in 1k batches)

I thought it could be a memory problem (gc?) with java so increased the memory, in steps, a lot, to no avail.

Anyone has tested leveldb java interfaces/implementation above and can give me some opinions/inputs?

I would rather use java (and the native java impl if at all possible) since the loading and preparation of the dataset  is much faster in java, and it would be easier to touch java impl if needed. But the insert performance and unpredictability is a no go.

Thanks in advance.